# Orchard CMS 1.7.2 - Media Library Always Empty

Tags: orchardcms-1.7

I'm new to Orchard and having installed a new instance of version 1.7.2 (I've gone the route of installing the source from a ZIP), the media library remains empty despite me uploading one or more images.

I can see the image get uploaded into the media folder within the "Web" project, but the media library never displays any of them.

I've used a SQL EXPRESS database, if that's of any consequence.

Is there any thing that I need to do to set it up, maybe?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a [known issue](https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/20222) on the Orchard site, which was the cause of the problem I was experiencing. Fixing this resolved the problem for me.